# Average YTD in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

[image]

The image above is a replica of a report that already exist. Now users want to see average Year to Day(YTD) per for each product. The idea is to aggregate the sum of each product and divide by the count of months. This report is group by month by year.

I understand using Window Function but I am running Sql Server 2008 so cannot frame. How do I go about this using SSRS?

Comment: Do you have the sum of each product and the count of months in your dataset?

Comment: I do have the sum of each product but not the count of months. I tried using CountDistinct on the date column(month) but that doesn't seems to work as I get error.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your query and the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it can be done using SSRS expression, but you can handle it in query level, something like:

```
 select 
 x.product
 , sum(x.prosum) sumbyMonthProduct
 , sum(x.prosum)/sum(x.countv) avgv
 from
 (select monthv, product
, sum(ytd_sale) as prosum
, count(monthv) as countv
 from tableName
 group by monthv, product
 ) x
 group by  x.product
```